# How to replace all occurrences of `someObject.ToString()` with `Convert.ToString(someObject);`

Tags: c#, regex

I want to search through my code and replace all instances of `someObject.ToString()` with `Convert.ToString(someObject)`.

For example if I have:

```
var x = someClassInstance.ToString()
```

I want to replace it with:

```
var x = Convert.ToString(someClassInstance)
```

Is it possible to do this through regular expression?

Comment: What do you want to search for? ?A literal `Object.string()` substring? You do not need  a  regex.

Comment: This is probably a very bad idea, especially when you realize C# is case sensitive and original changes in the question would never have compiled.

Comment: "replace in files" not good enough?

Comment: Are you doing this as an attempt to avoid a runtime `NullRefereceException`? If so, you could do **Find:** `.ToString()` **Replace:** `?.ToString() ?? ""`, which will then give you compile-time exceptions for any structs (since they don't support the `?.` operator), which you can then fix manually. But it's probably better to just fix your code by doing the necessary `null` checks instead.

Comment: Can you please tell me why down voted this post. I have a big project in which developer done mistake. They used toString.  So i want to change those expressions using regular expression find replace in all files.

Comment: Why? `Convert.ToString(someClassInstance)` just calls `someClassInstance.ToString()` anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution will differ slightly based on your environment, but for example in Notepad++:

Search for `([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)\.toString\(\)`.

Replace with `Convert.toString\($1\)`.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, you can use the following regex:

```
\b(\w+)\.ToString\(\)
```

It starts by matching a `Word boundary` and then graps all Word characters before the `dot` and `ToString()`. Note the escaped characters, they have special meaning in regex,

You then need to replace it with:

```
Convert.ToString($1)
```

Here '$1' will be replaced by the matched `Group 1` from the regex (the name of the method).

**Edit**:

The above regex will fail if the method name is a call to a method, like '`myMethod(param).ToString()`'.

I have changed the regex to accept anything not being a dot followed by '`ToString`' (since the code can already compile, there's no need for further syntax checking):

```
\b((?!\.ToString)(?:[\w.()+*/-])*?)\.ToString\(\)
```

Now it should include function calls.

Example of match: '`SomeFunction(Int32.MaxValue-1).ToString()`'

It will fail, if there are Spaces in the match.

Comment: It solve the problem to some extent . Just little doubt , can we achieve this using Roslyn. I just came to know it can parse c# code.

Comment: I don't know anything about Roslyn. Hope others can comment on that.